# Простая карусель на JQuery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую карусель картинок на JQuery
Никак не могу отловить условие, когда прекращать крутиться картинки влево/вправо по достижению конца.

```
              var carousel = $('.carousel').outerWidth();
          var list_item = $('.carousel li').length;
          var list_item_width = $('.carousel li').outerWidth() + 30;
          var list_count = (list_item * list_item_width);
          $('.next').click(function() {
            if($('.carousel').position.left <= list_count + 'px') {
            $('.next').show();
            $('.carousel').animate({
              left: '-=' + list_item_width
            }, 900);
        }
        else {
            $('.next').hide();
            return false;
        }
```

Все равно продолжает вращать картинки не смотря на то, что достигнут предел

Comment: position - это метод. Надо не position, а position(); Та же он возвращает число, так что + 'px' не нужно. а еще предлагаю посмотреть плагин jCarousel или jCarouselLite

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. У меня, к сожалению, задача от заказчика не использовать готовые плагины.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался вроде))

```
$('.next').click(function() {
            //alert(pos);
          if(($('.carousel').position().left) > list_count) {  
            $('.next').show();
            $('.carousel').animate({
              left: '-=' + list_item_width
            }, 900);
        }
        else {
            $('.next').hide();
            return false;
        }
```

Забыл скобки (($('.carousel').position().left) > list_count)

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте так:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($(".carousel").width() >= $(".carousel li").last().position().left){
        $(".carousel").animate({
            scrollLeft: 0
        },200);
    } else {
        $(".carousel").animate({
            scrollLeft: $(".carousel").scrollLeft() + list_item_width
        },200);
    }
});
```

только предварительно сделайте внутренний контейнер длинным чтобы все элементы могли в нем вместиться, а внешний `overflof: hidden;`

Comment: Вообще не крутит :)

Comment: а структура хтмл и цсс правила стоят правильно? Нужно добиться чтобы был скрулбар с overflow: auto или overflow: scroll. Я просто сам не давно делал карусель этим подходом и у меня работает замечательно

Comment: <div class="carousel-block">
        <ul class="carousel">
            <li><img src="test3_pic.jpg" alt="" title=""/></li>
            <li><img src="test3_pic.jpg" alt="" title=""/></li>
            <li><img src="test3_pic.jpg" alt="" title=""/></li>           
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="controll">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev" title="Назад">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next" title="Вперед">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

Comment: .carousel-block {
 position: relative;
 top: 350px;
 width:1050px; 
 overflow:hidden;
 height:235px;
}
.carousel {
 display:block;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:absolute;
 width:9999px;
 left:0px;
}
.carousel li {
 float:left;
 margin-right:30px;
 padding:20px 30px;
 background:#fff;
}

Comment: В html и css вроде все нормально. внешний блок с overflow:hidden а внутри ширина 9999